# Animate Between Classes Angular 2

Tags: animation, angular, ng-animate, ng-class

Is there an Angular 2 way to animate between classes?

```
<div class="home-carousel-head" id="full-screen-carousel" [ngClass]="{tab_one: tab_one, tab_two: tab_two, tab_three: tab_three}">
```

I want to fade out or fade in when the class changes between each tab, this was easy with Angular 1 and ng-animate but I am not seeing this functionality with Angular 2. What is the best practice in Angular 2 to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular animation module is about to be shipped. Currently you can use CSS animation. Fade-in/fade-out should be quite easy using CSS alone.